# Powerquery command to convert date format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a column Date of the following format `06-08-2000`.

I need to convert into the following format : `dd-mmm-yyyy` where `mmm` would be `{Jan, Feb, Mar, ...}`

So the output would be `06-Aug-2000`.

I am totally new to powerquery and this is my only task using it. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it clear now ?

Comment: Olaf provided you with an PowerShell answer in the comment and you tagged the question with PowerShell but your subject states Powerquery. What is it that you want?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your date column name is "**dt**". Your input format for the date "06-08-2000" (dd-mm-yyyy your case) is not a recognizable date format in power query. So you have to create a actual date formatted value first from your input date. Then with some couple of more steps you will get your required output

**Step-1:** Create a new column "new_date" in power query as below-

[image]

**Step-2:** Change the data type of newly created column "new_date" to "Date" type

**Step-3:** Go back to report by clicking "Close & Apply" button.

**Step-4:** New create a custom column using following DAX in the report

```
custom_date = FORMAT(your_table_name[new_date],"dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

Now you have your required formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI select your column.  Then you have a tab "Column tools".  Select it and you will see a format option. Enter `dd-mmm-yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original date is in column **date**, in Powerquery, add a Add Column ... Custom Column ... with below formula to convert

= Date.ToText([date],"dd-MMM-yyyy")